# Python trange from tqdm.contrib.telegram not work when build .pyw file with py installer

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-telegram-bot, tqdm

I'm using Python v3.10.10, pyinstaller package v 5.10.0, tqdm.contrib.telegram v4.65.0
When I use trange while running in visual studio code it work perfectly but when I build my source code as exe by pyinstaller, the file I built is .pyw (I want to run it silently) the the result only show on my telegram chat is

> TelegramIO

there is no processing after that it sends an error:

> NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Please help!

I've tried to run in vscode its ok.
I've tried to build by .py file then run the exe its ok.
I've tried to build by .pyw file then run the exe its fail.

Here is my whole code:

```
#progress bar telegram
from tqdm.contrib.telegram import tqdm, trange
from time import sleep
import os
from telegram import KeyboardButton,ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update, Bot, File, Chat, ChatMember, ChatMemberUpdated#, WebAppInfo
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ChatMemberHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
    filters,
)
import dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
#mycrypto
from mycrypto import mycrypto

LOCATION = range(1)

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    chatid = update.message.chat_id
    my_df = 100
    for i in trange(my_df, token=telegram_token, chat_id=chatid, desc ='process', miniters=5, maxinterval=200):
        sleep(0.5)

async def location(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    """Stores the location and asks for some info about the user."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    user_location = update.message.location
    await update.message.reply_text(
        f'{user.first_name}, {user_location.latitude}, {user_location.longitude}'
    )

async def cancel(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    """Cancels and ends the conversation."""
    msg_id = update.message.message_id
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "end conversation", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
        reply_to_message_id=msg_id
    )

    return ConversationHandler.END

def main() -> None:
    load_dotenv()
    global config,telegram_token
    config = {
    'telegramToken': os.environ['TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN']
    }
    telegram_token = config['telegramToken']
    telegram_token = mycrypto.crypto(telegram_token,'decrypt')
    application = Application.builder().token(telegram_token).build()
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            CommandHandler("start", start),
        ],
        states={
            LOCATION: [
                MessageHandler(filters.LOCATION, location),
                CommandHandler("cancel", cancel),
            ],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )
    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please provide the full traceback to the error.